# How to put different View into a List?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I new come to Xcode,

here is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                TestView().padding();
                TestView2().padding();
                TestView3().padding();
                TestView4().padding();
                  }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Place"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
              }
    }
}
```

one of the Testview:

```
struct TestView: View {
@Environment(\.editMode) var mode

@State var timeNow = ""
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let fmtr = DateFormatter()
    fmtr.dateFormat = "LLLL dd, HH:mm"
    fmtr.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:  "Asia/Hong_Kong")!
    return fmtr
}

var body: some View {
   
    Text("HK: " + timeNow)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            self.timeNow = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        }

}}
```

[My preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCQgK.png)

I want to "Press the Edit button, then I can delete different place's clock"

I read the tutorial on the internet,if want to delete "something", it should put "something" into the "List.

However, in Xcode, "View" is not variable or int or string, how can I put the different view into "List" and call it out or delete.

Or any other way to accomplish my purpose?

My final goal is: to press the "edit Button", and choose to delete a different place.

Future, i want to add another function, press "+ button" then can choose the different place and add to display.

Comment: Code should always be included as text in the question and not an image. And if you want to get some help then clearly describe what the issue is with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var locations: [String] = ["Asia/Hong_Kong"] // you can add additional location strings
    @State var isEditMode: EditMode = .inactive
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(locations, id: \.self) { location in
                    TestView(location: location)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Place"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
            .environment(\.editMode, self.$isEditMode)
        }
    }
}
    struct TestView: View {
        let location: String
        @State var timeNow = ""
        let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
        var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
            let fmtr = DateFormatter()
            fmtr.dateFormat = "LLLL dd, HH:mm"
            fmtr.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:  location)!
            return fmtr
        }
        var body: some View {
            Text("HK: " + timeNow)
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    self.timeNow = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
                }
        }
    }

This will be work.
```

Comment: thank you for your help, you provide a new method to me, but when i test the code, the "locations" display "Cannot declare local wrapped variable in result builder" I cant find any problem with your code

Comment: locations, isEditMode should be moved to outside of `var body~`. I edited code.